# function to flatten list in to single list

Tags: c, algorithm, linked-list

Given a linked list structure where every node represents a linked list and 
contains two pointers of its type:

(i) pointer to next node in the main list.
(ii) pointer to a linked list where this node is head.

Write a C function to flatten the list into a single linked list.

Eg.

If the given linked list is

```
  1 -- 5 -- 7 -- 10 
  |    |    | 
  2    6    8 
  |    | 
  3    9 
  | 
  4
```

then convert it to

```
1 - 2 - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 9 - 7 - 8 -10
```

My solution

```
struct node {
    int data; 
    struct node *fwd; //pointer to next node in the main list. 
    struct node *down; //pointer to a linked list where this node is head. 
}*head,*temp,*temp2; 

temp=head; 
while(temp->fwd!=NULL) {
    temp2=temp->fwd; 
    while(temp->down!=NULL) {
        temp=temp->down;
    } 
    temp->down=temp2;
    temp->fwd=NULL;
    temp=temp2;
 }
```

plz notify me if anything...other solutions and optimizations are welcome

Comment: My solution : 

struct node 
{ 
  int data; 

  struct node *fwd; //pointer to next node in the main list. 

  struct node *down; //pointer to a linked list where this node is head. 

}*head,*temp,*temp2; 

temp=head; 
while(temp->fwd!=NULL) 
{ 
    temp2=temp->fwd; 
    while(temp->down!=NULL) 
    { 
        temp=temp->down; 
    } 
    temp->down=temp2; 
    temp->fwd=NULL; 
    temp=temp2; 
} 

plz notify me if anything...other solutions and optimizations are welcome

Comment: @wilhelmtell: guessing from the way it is written you are right.

Comment: no it not homework...its a interview question.can you please suggest any better answer..

Comment: @sjngm It lacks the last part: "Or you get a D"

Comment: @prp list traveling seems too naive for a good interview question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First it's important to get it working. Because of `while(temp->fwd!=NULL)`, your solution doesn't work for these scenarios:

```
A) 1 -- 2     B) 1 -- 3
        |        |    |
        3        2    4
```

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *fwd; //pointer to next node in the main list.
    struct node *down; //pointer to a linked list where this node is head.
};

struct node *solve(struct node *head) {
    struct node *temp = head, *fwd;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        fwd = temp->fwd;
        while (temp->down != NULL) {
            temp = temp->down;
        }
        temp->down = fwd;
        temp->fwd = NULL;
        temp = fwd;
    }
    return head;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct node
        n12 = { 12, NULL, NULL },
        n11 = { 11, NULL, &n12 },
        n10 = { 10, NULL, &n11 },
        n8 = { 8, NULL, NULL },
        n7 = { 7, &n10, &n8 },
        n9 = { 9, NULL, NULL },
        n6 = { 6, NULL, &n9 },
        n5 = { 5, &n7, &n6 },
        n4 = { 4, NULL, NULL },
        n3 = { 3, NULL, &n4 },
        n2 = { 2, NULL, &n3 },
        n1 = { 1, &n5, &n2 },
        *result = solve(&n1);

    while (result != NULL) {
        printf("%d%s", result->data, result->down ? " - " : "");
        result = result->down;
    }
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** This of course doesn't deal with `node->down->fwd`. You may want to solve that using a recursive function, which is left as exercise.

Answer (score 1):

If you treat the 'down' link as being the left child pointer, and the 'forward' link as the right child pointer, then you are seeking an in-order traversal of a simple binary tree.  That is, you visit the node; then you visit the left (down) children, then you visit the right (forward) children.  It is very easy to write that as a recursive function.

Your solution would not traverse any of the tree if the first node had only a down pointer and no forward pointer.  Nor would it search downwards from the last pointer if that had down pointers (because it has no forward pointer).

I think (but I'm not certain - I haven't tested it) that your solution runs into trouble on bushier trees than the one in the example.  If node 2 had forward pointers, I think there would be problems getting that subtree searched.

Use recursion; it is trivial and reliable.  While you can eliminate simple tail recursion, this requires more than simple tail recursion.

Comment: If Jonathan's solution doesn't make sense to you, just look at your diagram of the list while tilting your head 45 degrees to the left.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct node* flatten_dfwalk(struct node * root)
{   

    struct node *lnode, *rnode, *temp;

    if (NULL == root)
    {
        return NULL;
    }


    lnode = flatten_dfwalk(root->down);
    rnode = flatten_dfwalk(root->next);

    if (NULL == lnode)
    {
        return root;
    }

    temp = lnode;
    while(lnode->next != NULL)
    {
        lnode = lnode->next;
    }

    lnode->next = root->next;
    root->next = temp;

    return root;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution looks OK to me. A minor change might be that from the diagrams of the solution, I would expect the answer should be a "horizontal" list (using the fwd pointers) rather then the vertical one (using the down pointers) that your solution produces

Answer (score -2):

```
    struct node * last;
    void dfs(struct node * root)
    {
        if(root)
        {
            dfs(root->down);
            if(last!=NULL)
            {
                last->next=root->next;
                last=NULL;
            }
            dfs(root->next);
            if(root->down)
            root->next=root->down;

            if(root->next==NULL&&root->down==NULL)
                last=root;
        }
    }
```